# How to add extra math to org-cdlatex-mode when starting emacs?

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

The org-cdlatex-mode helps to insert math latex symbols/tempelates in org-mode.

I would like to add some extra symbols/accents to it. I realized that the math accents are stored in the variable `cdlatex-math-modify-alist-comb` and if I add to that list in the scrach buffer, I will get the extra short key for the new symbol, for example running:

```
(add-to-list 'cdlatex-math-modify-alist-comb '(?o "\\operatorname" nil t t nil))
```

works as expected. However if I add the same line in the init file, the new key won't be added to the list and emacs complains with warning that the list variable is free!

I probably need to add to the list **after** it has been loaded, however I couldn't find any source of how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround I did is to create a function that adds them every time I call my math minor mode

```lisp
(define-minor-mode org-math-mode
  "Some config to write math on `org-mode'."
  :lighter "org-math-mode"
  (org-fragtog-mode 1)
  (org-cdlatex-mode 1)
  (lauremacs-cdlatex-add-math-symbols))

(defun lauremacs-cdlatex-add-math-symbols ()
  (add-multiple-into-list
   'cdlatex-math-symbol-alist-comb
   '(
     (?.  "\\cdot"   "\\dots")
     (?\; "\\;")
     (?C  ""         "\\mathbb{C}"   "\\arccos")  
     (?N  "\\nabla"  "\\mathbb{N}"   "\\exp")     
     (?Q  "\\Theta"  "\\mathbb{Q}")  
     (?R  "\\Re"     "\\mathbb{R}")  
     (?Z  ""         "\\mathbb{Z}")
     )))
```

where add to multiple is just a helper function that uses `add-to-list`

```lisp
(defun add-multiple-into-list (lst items)
    "Add each item from ITEMS into LST."
    (throw-unless (symbolp lst) "List should be a symbol.")
    (dolist (item items)
        (add-to-list lst item)))
```

This might lead to a very big `'cdlatex-math-symbol-alist-comb` but it didn't bothered me yet, a solution to this is adding to list if element is not there or something like this

Answer (score 1):

The variable that needs to be set in your case is `cdlatex-math-modify-alist`. The documentation of that variable says: `Any entries in this variable will be added to the default.`

Comment: It doesn't work. Adding to this variable doesn't even work when I evaluate it in the scract buffer

Comment: Have you tried restarting Emacs? If you check the code of the function `cdlatex-compute-tables`, you will see that `cdlatex-math-modify-alist-comb` is defined appending current values of `cdlatex-math-modify-alist` and `cdlatex-math-modify-alist-default`.

Comment: Yes, I have. emacs doesn't complain but I don't get the extra key that I wanted to add. I even tried `cdlatex-reset-mode` with no result!

Comment: Make sure that you set the variable before you load/require cd-latex in your .emacs.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit cdlatex.el and compile it. For example, I add `sum` with this piece of code:

```lisp
("sum"         "Insert \\sum_{i=1}{n}"
 "\\sum_{i=1}{n}?"           cdlatex-position-cursor nil nil t)
```

and it works.